# How to configure multiple TFS 2015 projects to point to the same Git repository?

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

We are currently using TFS 2015 in our department. Unfortunately, we have one big .NET solution which is shared across multiple teams.

In TFS, we have a configuration in place to have one project with several teams underneath. The problem is that each team has different needs in terms of configuration, Agile practices, and more. But these things cannot be customised since these teams are all part of the same TFS project.

In order to have a completely separate TFS configuration from the rest of the teams, having the ability to tailor the process, boards and configurations based on the specific needs of our team, **is there a way to configure a brand new TFS Project pointing to the existing Git repository that the existing project is pointing to?** Or is there any other viable option?

I've also checked [Linking git repository to multiple TFS projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960636/linking-git-repository-to-multiple-tfs-projects), but I'm not looking to create a Git submodule in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customizations you make occur at one of three levels:

- **Team level:** Add teams and configure Scrum and Kanban tools that are
  team specific, such as what appears on each team's backlogs and
  boards, adding work item templates, and more
- **Team project level:** Add or modify work item types, data fields,
  backlog levels, and other objects shared across teams
- **Object level:** Grant or restrict access to work tracking tools, which
  includes setting permissions for objects and the team project and
  assigning users or groups to specific access levels.

The method you use to customize team projects, which **impacts all teams**, depends on the **process model** you use. Anytime you create a team project, you must choose a process or process template based on the process model you use. So you can't choose a different template (*i.e. Agile, Scrum, CMMI*) for each team within a project. It's team project level. More details you could refer this tutorial [Choose a process](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/choose-process)

Answer (score 1):

No. Repositories are scoped to a team project. You're already taking the right approach in keeping everything within a single team project and creating teams.

You can customize each team's backlog appearance and behavior separately.

As for process template customizations, I'd recommend seeing if you can unify it so that there's a single applicable process template across all teams. Maintaining many different process templates is a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you choose a different template (i.e. Agile, Scrum, CMMI) for each team within a project and then customise it?